# element.addClass() AngularJS vs JQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, element

I've created [this plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/BbiYS2C23eKULPF343TR/preview) to check for a strange behaviour:
trying to perform a

```
element.addClass('someclass')

app.directive('svgElement', function () {
return {
  restrict: 'AE',
  replace:true,
  template:
    '<svg height="100" width="100">' +
    '<circle class="chart__circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />' +
    '</svg>',
  scope: {
  },
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    var children = element.children();
    var circle = angular.element(children[0]);
    circle.addClass("selected");
  }
}});
```

in a link function in a directive the function was executed but nothing happened. 
In the example plunker this was working and I realized why: it is not importing JQuery.

In my project the script section is:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
...
```

If I remove the JQuery dependency is working.
May I ask why is happening and how to solve the problem keeping JQuery?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure if you noticed that in the link function, you are still using the jquery add class function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation of `jQuery.fn.addClass` does not allow to set classes of SVG elements. It reads/sets className property which is different from same HTMLElements property. However jqLite (AngularJS `addClass` simpler version) doesn't have this problem because it deals with `class` attribute, not property.

To avoid your problem while still continue using jQuery in the project, avoid `addClass` method and set class using `setAttribute` method.

```
var circle = angular.element(children[0])[0];
var oldClass = circle.getAttribute('class');
circle.setAttribute('class', oldClass + ' selected');
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/rs7bDpzHEJUF6itU8A7a?p=preview

Other alternative is to use [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) API (IE10+):

```
var circle = angular.element(children[0])[0];
circle.classList.add('selected');
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/wZfzKeCUB9EOzK6ESCok?p=preview